# External CSS for SVG elements inside object tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

I have a svg with many rect element inside it and has been added to html using object tag. I need to write external css (just to change color on hover of rect elements) for all the rect elements.
Able to achieve this if I write styles inside svg. But how to achieve the same with external css ?

sample.html

```
<object class="svg" id="show-svg" data="sample.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>
```

sample.svg

```
<svg>
<style>
rect:hover {stroke: red !important}
</style>
<g>
<rect style=stroke:white width="82.020828"
         height="134.9375"
         x="13.229176"
         y="135.60417"
/>
<rect style=stroke:white width="82.020828"
         height="134.9375"
         x="13.229176"
         y="135.60417"
/>
</g>
</svg>
```

The above has css written inside svg and works fine.
But would like to achieve the same by writing external css outside svg, how to do it ?

Comment: Did you try `class`? HTML: `<rect class='my-class'/>` CSS: `.my-class { stroke: white; }`

Comment: nope. It is inside object tag as document. How to access elements inside object tag ? can you please give an example snippet ?

Comment: You can load the SVG file with the [``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) and add CSS

Comment: Basically you can't.